# How to send data form Windows Phone 8.1 to PC using TCP or UDP?

Tags: tcp, udp, windows-phone-8.1, send, system.net.sockets

I'm trying to send data between Windows Phone 8.1 app and my PC.
How to do this? Is there any other way to connect with my PC?
I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202864(v=vs.105).aspx).

But I can't add `System.Net.Sockets` to my project.
Any working example will be a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.Sockets and the docs you linked are for Windows Phone Silverlight apps. For a Windows Phone Runtime app you'll use Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket (TCP) or Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket (UDP).

See [How to connect with a stream socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ150599(v=win.10).aspx) and [How to connect with a datagram socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj635238.aspx) on MSDN for details.